# Django database file on linux missing

Tags: django

I recently transferred my django project folder from a windows pc to a linux machine, and ever since then my django app is reading its database from an unknown location. I confirmed this by deleting the database in my project folder, and somehow i can still see all my models in the admin.

And when i run the below code , i get the path to the database and on going to the directory i seenothing.

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
'/home/Files/Document/django/one/db.sqlite3'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run makemigrations and migrate commands/

Comment: Are you sure its reading anything? can you see the models or the data?

Comment: Perhaps it creates records through *migrations*?

Comment: Yes i ran makemigrations and migrate. No changes detected. And on the admin i get all the data from my models completely

Comment: and currently there is no database file in my project and i can still access everything in admin

Comment: You could use `lsof` in bash to see the open files of the Django process and grep for the "sqlite3" file.

Comment: try this once and reload. `touch wsgi.py`

Comment: Solved the issue by restarting the machine and running manage.py migrate. Thanks for the answers.